# How to add a field to Browsing Widgets partial form?

Tags: 7

I have a content type Task which has a field that references to other content type Project, so when I create a new Task, I can reference it to a project. I would like to add this to the Commons Browsing Widgets partial form.
[image: Where I would like to see the dropdown list]

How can I add a dropdown list to this form that shows the projects where user can link the task? I was trying to add it by adding it to code in .module file, in the form_commons_bw_partial_node_form_alter() part but I didnt manage to get it working..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can just do this by going to your content type, edit the field you want to show and check the "Display in the browsing widget mini-form". After all the trouble it seems quite simple..